# Calculating Quantum number from initial conditions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation

I have solved the particle in a box problem to get energy eigenstates and wave vectors:

$$E_{n}=\frac{\hbar^{2} k^2}{2m} ,\hspace{1cm} k_{n}=\frac{\pi n}{L}$$

And now I am trying to figure out how we could determine the quantum number $n$ from the initial properties. For instance if we give the particle a mass of say $0.2 \,\text{kg}$ and initial velocity $v=1\text{ ms}^{-1}$ and set $L=1.5\text{ m}$. How could we determine the quantum number $n$.

We note that we have associated de Broglie wavelength:

$$\lambda = \frac{h}{p}=\frac{h}{0.2}=5h$$

We note that our wave number is given by: $k=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}=\frac{2\pi}{5 h}$. However, this does not result in an integer $n$. What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1):

The eigensolutions of the particle in the box are characterized by the integer quantum number $n$. The wave functions belonging to eigenenergy $E_n$ are given by

$\varphi_n(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{L}}\sin(k_nx), 0\le x\le L$

with the $k_n$ you gave above. (This assumes the "box" extends from $x=0$ to $x=L$.)

In contrast, the eigenstates of a free particle are characterized by a wave number $k$, i.e. $k$ is the proper quantum number for a free particle. The wave functions are plane waves

$\psi_k(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{ikx}$

and are defined in all of space. The spectrum is continuous, so $k$ can take on any value.

When you say that you prepare the particle with speed $v$, resulting in a $k=2\pi/\lambda\ne k_n$ for any $n$, you are not preparing the particle in the box in an eigenstate but rather in a superposition of eigenstates:

$\psi_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\varphi_n(x)$

(Pitfall: The plane waves as stated above are $\delta$-normalized. When putting them in a box where $x$ is restricted to $[0,L]$, you have to rescale to $\psi_k(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt L}e^{ikx}$ to ensure normalization.)

The coefficients $c_n$ can be determined by calculating the scalar product:

$c_n = \langle\varphi_n|\psi_k\rangle = \int_0^L\mathrm dx\,\varphi_n^*(x)\psi_k(x)$.

However, the system will not stay in that state as time evolves b/c it's not an eigenstate. The time dependent state is then given by:

$\psi_k(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\varphi_n(x)e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}$.

---

Mathematical remark: Strictly speaking, the equality 
$\psi_k(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\varphi_n(x)$ does not hold. For arbitrary $k$, the boundary condition $\varphi(x=0)=0$, $\varphi(x=L)=0$ is violated by plane waves. Thus, the particle-in-a-box eigensolutions $\varphi_n$ cannot reproduce $\psi_k$ exactly. Mathematically speaking, the Hilbert space for the particle in the box is different from the one for free particles (the domains of the wave functions is different and boundary conditions are imposed).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer; it is very interesting and corresponds to what I thought (and have been taught via books etc.) but I was specifically given a question with these values and told to calculate $n_{r}$ of the particle, is there no way to do this? Thanks again!!

Comment: What you could do is, you could calculate the expectation value of $n$: $\langle n\rangle=\sum_n n |c_n|^2$

Answer (score 1):

The quantum mechanical wave functions you calculated are just eigenfunctions of the Hamilton operator of the system. A physical state is a *superposition* of several of those eigenstates. So, a physical state does not necessarily have a single quantum number $n$.

Also, specifying a velocity $v$ is not enough to characterize a state. In quantum mechanics, momentum is an operator which operates on wave functions. The classical momentum is just the expectation value of the operator, e.g.

$$
p = \int_0^L \psi^*(x)\ \hat{p}\ \psi(x)
$$

(And some factors of $i$ and $\hbar$ I don't remember)

Many, many wave functions will satisfy $p = 0.2\frac{\text{kg m}}{\text{s}}$. It is not enough to say what the expectation value is.